# How to split a data frame into multiple data frames based on columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( { 
    "Name" : ["gene1","gene2","gene3","gene4"] , 
    "T1" : [0.33,1,3,4],
    "T2" : [1.23,2.1,3.5,5.0], } )
```

Which looks like this:

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]:
    Name    T1    T2
0  gene1  0.33  1.23
1  gene2  1.00  2.10
2  gene3  3.00  3.50
3  gene4  4.00  5.00
```

What I want to do is group based on `T1` and `T2` (basically all columns from 2nd columns onward). Note that the column names follow no pattern and can be more than two.

The end result I hope to get is this:

```
T1
    Name    T1   
0  gene1  0.33  
1  gene2  1.00  
2  gene3  3.00  
3  gene4  4.00 

T2
    Name    T2
0  gene1    1.23
1  gene2    2.10
2  gene3    3.50
3  gene4    5.00
```

How can I achieve that?

I tried this but doesn't give what I want:

```
tlist = list(df.columns[1:])
for dft in df.groupby(tlist,axis=1):
    print df
```

Comment: In your hoped result you are not grouping, you are just listing the columns. If that's really what you want, you just have to set "Name" as an index. 
`df = df.set_index("Name")` and then print the results 
`for c in df.columns:
    print(df[c])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get there using `pd.melt()`:

```
melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Name', var_name='t_col')

for t_col, sub_df in melted.groupby('t_col'):
    print(sub_df)

    Name t_col  value
0  gene1    T1   0.33
1  gene2    T1   1.00
2  gene3    T1   3.00
3  gene4    T1   4.00
    Name t_col  value
4  gene1    T2   1.23
5  gene2    T2   2.10
6  gene3    T2   3.50
7  gene4    T2   5.00
```